# Threading in C# not correspond

Tags: c#, multithreading

i want to take the exam C# ref 70-483.
but when i copy and paste the program into my visual studion 2012.
the result is not the same as the book.

who is right then ?
[image]

Comment: What is the topic you're currently reading about?

Comment: Short answer is, they're both right, because there is no right here, as long as you get all the messages. Multithreading has inherent race conditions like this, which depending on the speed of the computers, what they're doing, and about a billion other factors, will behave subtly different in each case, and none of them are wrong.

Comment: Without synchronization you can't predict which threads will execute in which order - this includes the main thread.

Comment: You'd never get `ThreadProc: 10` with that code

Comment: I missed that part, I focused on the ordering. The book output is actually buggy, correct.

Comment: Try using a value like 100 as the parameter in the .Sleep statements. Sleep(0) shouldn't wait at all.

Comment: `Sleep(0)` could trigger a task switch.

Comment: These exams always have a lot of mistakes, an inevitable consequence of printing code on dead wood.  Google "exam 70-483 errata" to find corrections.

Answer (score 3):

The book shows the wrong output!!

Look at this line

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

It will loop 10 times starting with 0 and ending with 9.

The book output shows it looping 11 times!  Starting with 0 and ending with 10!

So the code is correct, but it is a printing error in the book for the output.  And shows a lack of attention to detail.

Comment: This is correct but does not explain the differences in the ordering of the outputs, which the OP was probably asking about.